# Looping in Robot Framework not incrementing/persisting a variable value

Tags: robotframework

I have the code below that doesn't seem to persist the value of a variable. I am trying to increment it per call however the increment is not persistent in the variable.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  lib.py
*** Variables ***
${x}    0
${inc}  1
*** Keywords ***
My keyword
    ${x} =   evaluate   ${x}+${inc}
    Log To Console  ${x}
#    [return]    ${x}

*** Test Cases ***
Run endless loop
    Run Endless Loop  My keyword
```

=================================================================
lib.py

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


def call_keyword(keyword):
    return BuiltIn().run_keyword(keyword)


def run_endless_loop(f):
    while True:
        call_keyword(f)
```

Am curious what's happening here...

Answer (score 1):

Your keyword works fine, only you are incrementing a local variable.
So in every iteration `x` will be `0` and it will be incremented to `1`.

You have to store the returned value on suite level using the `Set Suite Variable` keyword.

```
*** Variables ***
${x}    0
${inc}  1

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    My keyword
    My keyword
    My keyword

*** Keywords ***
My keyword
    ${x} =   evaluate   ${x}+${inc}
    Set Suite Variable    ${x}
    Log To Console  ${x}
```